# generic graphics driver for mirroring

Tags: windows, video, windows-7, driver, device-driver

Is it possible to write an Windows generic graphics driver that will 1) use the currently installed driver for standard monitor out AND 2) perform some custom stuff with the video buffers (like mirror/stream to other video hardware). Something like what "connect to projector - mirror" does in Windows 7.

If this is not possible, can I write some driver that will hook somehow to the current graphics driver and take video buffers for further mirroring/streaming?

As far as I know, the existing drivers might be using COPP or some other protections when using Blu-ray sources or such, so how to avoid this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does Mirror Driver ([msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff568315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) suit your requirement?